# Printing struct in a format suitable for copy/paste to tests as "wantResult" value

Tags: go

I need to write tests for a function where the return result is a slice of large structs. It means that you need to write a test where "wantResult" should be filled with all these structs. The fastest way to fill it is to call a function and do copy/paste of the result into the test. However, I found that it is not easy to print a struct in a suitable format where you can just copy/paste it.

```
fmt.Printf("%v",myStruct)
```

will print something like this:
`[{field A field B field C} {field A field B field C}]` i.e. no quotes for strings, no commas between fields.

```
fmt.Printf("%+v",myStruct)
```

will print something like this:
`[{field A:value A field B:value B field C:value C} {field A:value A field B:value B field C:value C}]` - also no quotes, no commas between fields.

Finally, I come up with the reflect solution which looks like this:

```
for _, oneStruct := range gotResult {
                s := reflect.ValueOf(&oneStruct).Elem()
    typeOfs := s.Type()
    fmt.Println("{")
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        switch f.Type().Name() {
        case "string":
                        fmt.Printf("%v:\"%v\",\n", typeOfs.Field(i).Name, f.Interface())
        default :
                        fmt.Printf("%v:%v,\n", typeOfs.Field(i).Name, f.Interface())
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("},")
}
```

It works fine for simple flat structures with int, float and string field types. However, it looks cumbersome. Does anybody know something more elegant for this purpose?

Comment: I would dump it as JSON and rehydrate it from that.

Comment: I tried solutions like this:
json.MarshalIndent(myStruct, "", "\t")
but it prints field names with quotes, which is also not suitable for copy/paste. Maybe, you mean something else.

Comment: You can't copy/paste into a `.go` file, no - it's not Go, it's JSON. But you can just re-ingest the JSON you output using `json.Unmarshal`.

Comment: Not that it would make copy+paste output for all cases, but did you try using `%#v`? It's documented as `a Go-syntax representation of the value`. Otherwise you can use a standard serialization format as suggested, or write your own formatter that does what you want with `GoString`

Comment: Use `%#v` as suggested by JimB. This format qualifies types with a package name.  If that gets in the way, you can edit by hand or use a regexp to clean it up.

Comment: You are right! %#v returns exactly what is needed. Somehow I overlooked it. Thanks, everyone!